# Enzyme Test Code Memory cleanup

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have been looking at a lot of examples for testing react and redux applications using Enzyme and Jest, and there are very few that even mention code cleanup. When using `shallow` or `mount` do you not explicitly need to call `unmount` or `detach` to try to keep the memory bloat and runtime down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a case where we will want to use `detach` to cleanup. Let's look at the simple `shallow` and `mount` case first.

**Assigning to variables**

This 'simple' case is where we simply assign the render to a `var`/`const`/`let`.

If we look at the (cut down) example of using Jest and Enzyme from the [Enzyme Github](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme).

```
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('renders three <Foo /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(3);
  });

  it('renders an `.icon-star`', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.icon-star')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
  });
});
```

We can see the `shallow` method being called and the result being assigned to a `const`. The result is a `ShallowWrapper` object.

As `const` [has a block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) when the execution leaves the block it is defined - in this case the test arrow function - [the Javascript engine will automatically deallocate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection) the `ShallowWrapper` memory.

It's because of this we don't need to worry about unmounting - this is only used to test specific Component lifecycle methods.

**Attaching Components to DOM**

We can also attach components to the DOM.

If we look at the test case automatically generated by the `create-react-scripts`.

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

This example doesn't use Enzyme, but it's the same concept as to when you use `attachTo` in the Enzyme `mount` function.

We can see our Component is being attached to a `div` in the document and then `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` being called to cleanup. [This is actually what `detach` calls.](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/detach.html)

We need to do this cleanup because a reference to our rendered Component exists outside our block scope and therefore will **not** be deallocated when execution exits this block.

Comment: What if you did the `Enzyme` `mount` within a `beforeEach` - would you then need to do a clean up ?

Comment: @Norfeldt If you are attaching to a DOM Node, you should call `unmountComponentAtNode` (or `detach`) no matter where you are mounting. It's really about the fact `document` has a global scope so will not be deallocated from memory